# InstallShield 2016 Express project doesn't load in Visual Studio 2017 update 15.3

Tags: visual-studio-2017, installshield

I have a .NET 4.5.2 WPF solution containing an InstallShield 2016 Express project. I'm using Visual Studio 2017. Everything was working until I updated Visual Studio to 15.3. Now the InstallShield project fails to load when I open the solution. I get this message:

> These projects are either not supported or need project behavior impacting modifications to open in this version of Visual Studio. Projects not displayed either require no changes or will automatically be modified such that behavior is not impacted. For details, see [More information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/porting/port-migrate-and-upgrade-visual-studio-projects?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(VS.ReviewProjectAndSolutionChangesDialog.Upgrade)%26rd%3Dtrue).
>
> **Unsupported**
>
> This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following
>   projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of
>   Visual Studio may not support them.  For more information on enabling
>   these project types or otherwise migrating your assets, please see the
>   details in the "Migration Report" displayed after clicking OK.
>      - Setup, "C:\Develop\DxImporter\DesktopWebUiV2\Setup\Setup.isproj"

The "More information" link suggested installing the [Wix Toolset Visual Studio 2017 Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RobMensching.WixToolsetVisualStudio2017Extension), so I did, but it didn't help.

Has anyone else had this problem, and if so, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexera tech support informed me that InstallShield 2016 Express SP1 or SP2 should work with VS 2017 update 15.3. To fix my issue, they suggested uninstalling and reinstalling InstallShield. I had SP1 installed, so I uninstalled that, then installed SP2. That fixed it.

**Edit:** I recently had to uninstall and reinstall VS 2017, after which I ran into the same problem with my InstallShield project. This time I tried repairing InstallShield Express SP2 rather than uninstalling and reinstalling it. It worked!

Comment: OK, you can set your own answer as the accepted answer.